# runtime/nativehr error

Tags: 2010

I am not very well versed on sharepoint, but am 'in charge' anyway. We are running sharepoint 2010 for our organization portal. The site comes up and everything displays fine, you can click to view items, etc. But when anything is attempted in manage content and structure - delete, add, move, to any list or list item, we are getting a runtime error. When I go out to a list and try and add a new item, I get the nativehr/nativestack error.

This happened today, yesterday was ok. I was informed by our Networking admin that a db backup had been performed yesterday afternoon. No restore, just a backup. Not sure if that would have any bearing.

They have also restarted the db server, and I was able to submit an event to a calendar right away but soon after everything went back to being inaccessible.

Has anything like this happened to anyone else? I would like to know how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more info. ULS log for this error would be helpful to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the logs! There was about 5 GBs worth. According to our Networking Admin, he reduced the logs by going from Full to Simple. Then turned it back to Full again once it cleared.